# QGIS: automatic generalization

Tags: qgis, generalization, smoothing

I'm trying to generalize my line features with QGIS. I've tried the "Generalizer"-Plugin, but can't get the results i want. I'd like to generalize my line as shown in the image.

I've tried the "vertex reduction", followed by the "Chaiken's Algorithm" (for example input value: level 10, weigth 4). The smoothing is just too weak and not enough generalized. If i add the level to get a higher smoothing, it results in a failure (memory error). Which algorithms or input values could you recommend?[image]